# asp.net web.config gloablization not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-config, iis-6

I have an asp.net mvc application and I am trying to test resource files for my application. Application is deployed on IIS 6.0 (on windows server 2008 r2). I placed a folder "es" (with resource dll files) under "bin" directory of the application and made the following change in the web.config file

```
<globalization uiculture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

When I browse the application it still displays strings from english resource file. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that with MVC, there is a bit more involved.  See if this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx) helps

Hope this helps!

Matt

Comment: PS--I don't think that IIS version will matter as long as it is IIS 6+.  Also, the tutorial I referenced assumes you are using MVC3.  Cheers!